# In CSS, is it possible to check if a particular class is already defined

Tags: html, css, if-statement

In CSS, is it possible to check if a particular class is already defined in any previous CSS, like an if statement, `if (defined('.main'.) { do this} else {do that}` , something like this.

Is this possible in CSS or at least CSS 3.0 ?

Comment: Im afraid not best to use jquery .class etc if you want this functionality

Comment: My basic requirement is, I have one CSS, android.css dynamically added if the browser is Android. I have another CSS if the visit is from UK, uk.css. Both has independent styles. But if I have to define some CSS for those from UK, using Android browser, instead of creating a new css android-uk.css. So if a checking is possible, I could have written inside android.css, if uk.css is defined on top, add a particular css rule.

Comment: If I understood well, you could add classes `android` and `uk` on a parent and define "prefixed" rules in CSS like `.android.uk element .class { /* special case */ }`. Though except if you really really need browser detection, you'd better stick to Media Queries...

Comment: You don't define a class in CSS, but use it as part of a selector in a selector rule. What you can do is detect in CSS if a class was defined in HTML code, and only if it's the targetted element, one of its parents or preceding sibling of this element or of one of its parents.

Answer (score 2):

try framework like http://lesscss.org/ for that. plain css do not support this.